# Doing async SSL/TLS handshake Python

Tags: python, openssl, python-asyncio, aiohttp, python-sockets

I have this traditional synchronous code which connects to a website and gathers the SSL/TLS version along with server certificate details:

```
import ssl, socket

SERVER_HOSTNAME = "www.example.com"

try:
    sock = socket.create_connection((SERVER_HOSTNAME, 443), timeout=3)
    ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
    ssock = ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=SERVER_HOSTNAME)
    tls_info = {
        'version': ssock.version(),
        'peercert': ssock.getpeercert(),
    }
except Exception as e:
    quit(e)
```

How can I port this to async so I can gather this information for multiple sites in parallel?  I found asyncore, but it's being deprecated.  aioopenssl looks like a possibility, but I can't find a good usage example.  aiohttp seems to support it, although it would be overkill since I'm just looking to do a handshake and don't need to do an actual HTTP request.

Comment: I have the same exact problem. Found a solution yet?